# 3 wire cooktop (réduit black & grounds) to a 4 wire ourlet (red black wite & ground)

Tags: electrical

How can Connect a 3 wire cooktop (red black & ground) to a 4 wire ourlet (red black wite & ground)

Comment: The Answer already listed is 100% correct **provided the cooktop is truly a 3-wire cooktop**. There have been a bunch of posts, some with cooktops/ovens but mostly with dryers, where the "3-wire device" is actually an older (used) device that had a 3-wire cord because the previous location didn't have separate ground & neutral available. If this is a new cooktop then that should not be the case. But if it is older, **tell use the make/model # and we can check it out to be sure**.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- generally, its only ovens, ranges, and dryers that have that problem -- just about all cooktops are truly 3-wire (i.e. no neutral needed)

Answer (score 2):

Connect red, black and green/bare (ground.) Put a wire nut on the unused white in the wall box, in case a different appliance is used later that needs it.

**Or:** If using a plug into a 4-wire receptacle, just don't connect to the neutral (white) blade of the plug.